# Derive the moment generating function with a single variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, moment-generating-functions

The question simply says:

> Derive the MGF with a single variable (don't give memorized equation).

I'm not entirely sure what this question is asking, and I know how to derive the MGF if I knew that the random variable was binomial or geometric for example. However, I don't know how to derive it for a single variable. What I'm thinking is this:

$$
\begin{split}
e^x    &= \frac{x^0}{0!}+\frac{x^1}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!} + \ldots \\
e^{xt} &= 1+xt+\frac{x^2t^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3t^3}{3!} + \ldots \\
M(t) = E(e^{xt}) &= 1+tE(x)+\frac{t^2}{2!}E(x^2)+\frac{t^3}{3!}E(x^3) + \ldots
\end{split}
$$

I'm not sure if this is the answer?

Is it asking to derive the general formula for the MGF for a discrete random variable (since we haven't done continuous r.v.'s in class yet).

I know that for a discrete pmf, the MGF is:

$$M(t)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}e^{tx_i}p_i$$

EDIT:

So should I say then that:

$$M_{X}(t)=E(e^{tX})$$

$$=E\Bigg(\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{(tx)^r}{r!}\Bigg)$$

$$=\sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{E(X^r)}{r!}*t^r$$

Comment: I believe so. Remember that the MGF encodes the moments of a random variable by coefficients. In general, a generating function for a sequence encodes it by the coefficients of a power series (see Wilf's text _Generatingfunctionology_ for more.

Comment: sorry, just confused if you're saying that my answer is correct? is the answer $1+tE(x)+(t^2)/(2!)E(x^2}+...$

Comment: The short version, yes. The MGF is simply the expectation of the random variable $e^{tX}.$ Now use the law of the unconscious statistician (the way you compute expectations of functions of variables).

Comment: Sorry im still getting a little confused. are you saying that I need to show that $E(e^{xt})=\sum_{0}^{\infty}e^{tx_i}p_i$?

Comment: @SeanRoberson i just made an edit. would you mind checking and seeing if im understanding what you were saying? and is my edit the correct solution?

Comment: This is an okay solution.